# can't figure out how to list all rows from MYSQL in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I have finished my page and want to list all the data in my database for the current customer id selected and I can only seem to get the first row in the DB to list, I can't get all of them.

I have tried a while loop but I just can't seem to get the logic. Any help would be appreciated
Here is the entire code for the page. I want to use the last table on the page to show all the customer data.

I have labeled it with a comment if you are looking for the section im referring to.

> // Display all data for customer from db. -- cant seem to figure this part out [while loop?]

```php
<?php
// Check existence of id parameter before processing further
if(isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){
    // Include config file
    require_once "../includes/config.php";
    
    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers, orders WHERE customers.id = orders.customerId AND customers.id = ?";
    
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);
        
        // Set parameters
        $param_id = trim($_GET["id"]);
        
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                
                // Retrieve individual field value
                $customerId = $row['customerId'];
                $name = $row['name'];
                $address = $row['address'];
                $phone = $row['phone'];
                $email = $row['email'];
                $other1 = $row['other1'];
                $other2 = $row['other2'];
                $notStartedCheckbox = $row['notStartedCheckbox'];
                $dateToWork = $row['dateToWork'];
                $finishedCheckbox = $row['finishedCheckbox'];
                $dateTimeFinished = $row['dateTimeFinished'];
                $paidCheckbox = $row['paidCheckbox'];
                $dateTimePaid = $row['dateTimePaid'];
                $paidWith = $row['paidWith'];
                $notes = $row['notes'];
            } else{
                // URL doesn't contain valid id parameter. Redirect to error page
                header("location: error.php");
                exit();
            }
            
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>View Record</title>
    <!-- stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/16d3fe3a77.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        .wrapper{
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <h3 class="mt-5 mb-3"><?php echo $row['name'] . ' | ' . $row['address'] . ' | ' . $row['phone'] . ' | ' .  $row['email'] . '  ' . $row['other1'] . ' ' . $row['other2']  ; ?></h3>
                    <!-- Submit a form that adds a new job for a customer -->
                    <form action="newWorkOrder.php" method="post">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>Customer ID (Auto)</th>
                        <th>Started</th>
                        <th>Work Date</th>
                        <th>Service</th>
                        <th>Finished</th>
                        <th>Finished Date/Time</th>
                        <th>Paid</th>
                        <th>Paid Date/Time</th>
                        <th>Paid With</th>
                        <th>Notes</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="radio" checked name="customerId" id="customerId" value="<?php echo $row['customerId'] ?>"></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="notStartedCheckbox" id="notStartedCheckbox" value="0"></td>
                            <td><input type="date" name="dateToWork" id="dateToWork"></td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="service" id="service">
                                    <option value="mowing">Mowing</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="finishedCheckbox" id="finishedCheckbox" value="0"></td>
                            <td><input type="datetime-local" name="dateTimeFinished" id="dateTimeFinished"></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="paidCheckbox" id="paidCheckbox" value="0"></td>
                            <td><input type="datetime-local" name="dateTimePaid" id="dateTimePaid"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="paidWith" id="paidWith"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="notes" id="notes"></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </form>
                    <hr>

                    <!-- Display the table -->
                    <?php 
                    echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
                    echo "<thead>";
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<th>Started</th>";
                        echo "<th>Work Date</th>";
                        echo "<th>Service</th>";
                        echo "<th>Finished</th>";
                        echo "<th>Finished Date/Time</th>";
                        echo "<th>Paid</th>";
                        echo "<th>Paid Date/Time</th>";
                        echo "<th>Paid With</th>";
                        echo "<th>Notes</th>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</thead>";

                    // Display all data for customer from db. -- cant seem to figure this part out [while loop?]
                    echo "<tbody>";
                        echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['notStartedCheckbox'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['dateToWork'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['service'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['finishedCheckbox'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['dateTimeFinished'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['paidCheckbox'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['dateTimePaid'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['paidWith'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</table>";
                ?>
                    
        <br>
                    <p><a href="../index.php" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the section I can't get to work properly, it will display all rows after I submit a new form, but won't show any pre-existing data from my database.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){    
                    echo "<tr>";
                            if($row['notStartedCheckbox'] == true) {
                                echo "<td>" . 'Started' .  "</td>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<td style='color: red'>Not Started</td>";
                            }

                            echo "<td>" . $row['dateToWork'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['service'] . "</td>";

                            if($row['finishedCheckbox'] == true) {
                                echo "<td>" . 'Finished' .  "</td>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<td style='color: red'>Not Finished</td>";
                            }

                            echo "<td>" . $row['dateTimeFinished'] . "</td>";

                            if($row['paidCheckbox'] == true) {
                                echo "<td>" . 'Paid' .  "</td>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<td style='color: red'>Not Paid</td>";
                            }

                            echo "<td>" . $row['dateTimePaid'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['paidWith'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
```

Comment: yes, loop the results, and echo that row

Comment: yea, i've tried, i made two dummy rows in the database and i can only get one of them to show up. I've tried `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` and `while(mysqli_fetch_array($result))` but i can only get one row in the database to list

Comment: Please show us how yo u implemented your ``while ($row = mysqli_....)` code since it's obvious why you only get one row with your current code (you only fetch one row). Also, storing the values in separate variables makes no sense, since you're not actually using any of them.

Comment: I didn't realize that you didn't need them as seperate variables.  [link](https://shrib.com/#Joziah4QdAqYN) So all the new data shows after i submit a new form it but the preexisting data wont show

Comment: Don't use `while` loop ! use `for` or `foreach` instead. and use `pdo` for easier `mysql ` connection

Comment: Thanks, i'll give for or for each loops a shot, if i cant figure it out thats fine, i'm experiencing a bunch of issues after the fact. i'm still learning and doing this as a fun project so i'll go back to the drawing board. i'll try classes and objects and restructuring the entire program.